# Error: The NgModule 'ApprovalModule' needs to be compiled using the JIT compiler, but '@angular/compiler' is not available

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng, angular13

ERROR Error: **Uncaught (in promise): Error: The NgModule 'ApprovalModule' needs to be compiled using the JIT compiler, but '@angular/compiler' is not available**.

JIT compilation is discouraged for production use-cases! Consider using AOT mode instead.
Alternatively, the JIT compiler should be loaded by bootstrapping using '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic' or '@angular/platform-server',
or manually provide the compiler with 'import "@angular/compiler";' before bootstrapping.
Error: The NgModule 'ApprovalModule' needs to be compiled using the JIT compiler, but '@angular/compiler' is not available.

JIT compilation is discouraged for production use-cases! Consider using AOT mode instead.
Alternatively, the JIT compiler should be loaded by bootstrapping using '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic' or '@angular/platform-server',
or manually provide the compiler with 'import "@angular/compiler";' before bootstrapping.

> When i Navigate one menu to another i am getting above error.
> "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~13.0.1",
> "@angular/cli": "~13.0.1",
> "@angular/compiler-cli": "~13.0.1",
> "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
> "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.8",
> "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
> "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
> "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
> "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
> "karma": "~5.1.0",
> "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
> "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.3",
> "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
> "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
> "protractor": "~7.0.0",
> "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
> "tslint": "~6.1.0",
> "typescript": "~4.4.3",
> "primeflex": "3.1.0",
> "primeicons": "5.0.0",
> "primeng": "13.0.2",
> "prismjs": "1.9.0",
> "rxjs": "~6.6.0"

> Node:v16.13.1,Npm:8.1.2

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.